# How to write query to find the number of appointments with a followup appointment based on time?

Tags: mysql, sql

I wrote the following query in order to return the number of appointments per employee, per day that have a repeat appointment in a certain time frame. I want to add to this query and have it return the count for more than one time period. For instance, I want a column that gives me 1-30 days and another column that gives me 30-90 days. How can I do this?

```
select
  appt1.employee_id, 
  Date(appt1.appointmentTime) as first_appt_date, 
  COUNT(DISTINCT(appt1.id)) as appt_with_followup 
from appointment as appt1
join appointment as appt2 on appt1.customer_id = appt2.customer_id
        and DATEDIFF(appt2.appointmentTime, appt1.appointmentTime) BETWEEN 1 AND 30
        and appt1.employee_id is not null
group by appt1.employee_id, Date(appt1.appointmentTime)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use SUM and CASE instead of COUNT, like below.  Also you want a left join or you will not get any results that have no follow appt.

```
select
  appt1.employee_id, 
  Date(appt1.appointmentTime) as first_appt_date, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(appt2.appointmentTime, appt1.appointmentTime) BETWEEN 1 AND 30 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 30_DAY,
  SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(appt2.appointmentTime, appt1.appointmentTime) BETWEEN 30 AND 90 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 90_DAY
from appointment as appt1
left join appointment as appt2 on appt1.customer_id = appt2.customer_id
                         and appt2.appointmentTime > appt1.appointmentTime
group by appt1.employee_id, Date(appt1.appointmentTime)
```

Not sure this is exactly what you want -- a user with 3 appointments for example will have two rows, 1 with 2 followups and 1 with 1.  You really only want the first one for each user.  To get that do the following:

```
select
  appt1.employee_id, 
  Date(appt1.appointmentTime) as first_appt_date, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(appt2.appointmentTime, appt1.appointmentTime) BETWEEN 1 AND 30 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 30_DAY,
  SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(appt2.appointmentTime, appt1.appointmentTime) BETWEEN 30 AND 90 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 90_DAY
from (
  SELECT a.*, ROW_NUMBER(PARTITION BY employee_id ORDER BY appointmentTime ASC) as RN
  FROM appointment a
) as appt1
left join appointment as appt2 on appt1.customer_id = appt2.customer_id
                         and appt2.appointmentTime > appt1.appointmentTime
WHERE appt1.RN = 1
group by appt1.employee_id, Date(appt1.appointmentTime)
```